Where can I find a good spectrally-resolved altitude profile (or limb view) of airglow?
There are lots of RGB photos of airglow from ISS (e.g. ISS043-E-143486), many of them can even be downloaded in NEF raw format to analyze the brightnesses in a bit more linear form than the cooked JPEG. But I'd like to find some data with better spectral resolution, like 16 or more bands covering 400..700 nm and with a good enough resolution in altitude to resolve the double layer structure of the airglow (the bluish higher layer + the yellowish lower one).
I've found one paper [1] that shows an explicit spectrum of the limb view of the Earth's airglow. The spectrum looks like this:

Here one can already see the double layer structure and get some idea of the spectral altitude profile of the airglow. But it's a scan (or a photo) of a page in the journal, which implies that not only are the brightnesses unreliable as they are, but also some non-uniform glare is present that makes it impossible to use this image for quantitative analysis. I'm not even discussing its noisiness.
Another source I tried using was the data from the OSIRIS instrument on the Odin spacecraft (accessible here). The problem here is that the data I could get appear to have quite low integration time, so that the pseudocontinuum is not even registered (most of the spectrum points are negative, which implies S/N ratio is useless). Here's how a bunch of spectra from different view tangent altitudes look at one of the scans:

And I don't even know how to search among all of these scans for something that would be useful. The instrument is said to be capable of 10 second exposure, but the scan I downloaded (the file referenced in a code example, OSIRIS_L1_Spectrograph_054300_2011-02-06_v2-0.nc) only has 1 second of exposure in all samples (though maybe even 10 seconds would be insufficient).
So, my question is: where can I find a better spectral profile either of the volume emission ratio, or just of the limb view of the airglow?
References

Mende, S. B., G. R. Swenson, S. P. Geller, R. A. Viereck, E. Murad, and C. P. Pike (1993), Limb view spectrum of the Earth's airglow, J. Geophys. Res., 98(A11), 19117–19125, doi:10.1029/93JA02282

